# how to convert a perl + cpp into an standalone application

Tags: c++, perl

I am a newbie in programming. I am working on a big recognition algorithm that contains many inputs, parameters and outputs, and needs to call external binaries made by my teammates. So far I have already had a perl script that glued everything together. This time I want to attend a recognition contest, but it has been asked to submit only one standalone application. Is there any quick solution?

Comment: Perl scripts can't generally be compiled into executables. But you could look into the [`PAR`](https://metacpan.org/module/pp) tools that pack a perl interpreter, required modules, and your source code into one fat executable. I don't personally use this so I have no idea how this squares with precompiled C++ programs.

Comment: Consider looking at applications that have an embedded Perl interpreter such as Irssi and rxvt-unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I like perl , and I also like C/C++. so I don't wanna suffer from this.
I wrote a github project to solve this issue.

please see:
    https://github.com/tlqtangok/perlcpp

a short example is here :
P_eval("$a=2;$a=$a**10;"); 
Int("a") ;   // a= 1024